# ajax request to different host

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have the following javascript in my webpage:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    alert('resp received, status:' + xhr.status + ', responseText: ' + xhr.responseText);
  }                                                                       
};                                                                        
xhr.send(null);
```

this executes and finishes w/ a readyState of 4, status of 0, and empty responseText and responseXML.  i know that it is actually sending the request b/c i tried sending the xhr to a server on my machine, and the server does in fact respond.  why am i not getting anything in the responseText?  does it have something to do w/ the fact that the xhr is going to a different server?

when i open up the js debugger and type 'xhr' to inspect the object i get this:

> XMLHttpRequest
>   DONE: 4
>   HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2
>   LOADING: 3
>   OPENED: 1
>   UNSENT: 0
>   abort: function abort() {
>   addEventListener: function addEventListener() {
>   dispatchEvent: function dispatchEvent() {
>   getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders() {
>   getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader() {
>   onabort: null
>   onerror: null
>   onload: null
>   onloadstart: null
>   onprogress: null
>   onreadystatechange: function () {
>   open: function open() {
>   overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType() {
>   readyState: 4
>   removeEventListener: function removeEventListener() {
>   responseText: ""
>   responseXML: null
>   send: function send() {
>   setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader() {
>   status: 0
>   statusText: ""
>   upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
>   withCredentials: false

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> does it have something to do w/ the
>   fact that the xhr is going to a
>   different server?

Yep, you cannot send requests to another servers via AJAX. Whereas, you can send your requests from the server-side. Thus you'll need to implement following workflow:
Your page -> Your server -> Third party server -> Your server -> Your page , where "->" means sending data.

Comment: +1 an effective very simple proxy. I have written one of these in PHP using CURL.

Answer (score 3):

You MAY do cross-domain requests if server is configured to allow it: see [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) and google about Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-site scripting is a common way of injecting code into someone else's web page. To limit this, most browsers now stop the client-side developer from creating a JavaScript request (typically through `XMLHttpRequest`) to web pages located on a different domain to the original page.

You can get around this simply by creating a dummy script on your domain that forwards the same request to the page you actually want. For example, in your case, you would create a request to `http://mydomain.com/google.php` (or whatever scripting language you prefer), which would then download the Google page using [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) or similar and simply `echo` it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do cross-domain requests with javascript. The best way round this is to use your server as a proxy.