# Copy content of iframe into a div with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to copy some parts of html content (  inside an iframe ) into a external div. In my page i have a form inside an iframe and i want to copy some parts of this form and append in another div, outside of the iframe.

Ex.

```
<section>       
<iframe id="reg01" class="registration-form" name="registration" src="https://www.website.com/registrationSteps/newUser.jsp" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<div id="registration"> Some content of iframe here </div>

</section>
```

Comment: if you're using jQuery, you can grab the contents of the iframe with `$('iframe').contents()`

Comment: have you tried .clone() function ? [link](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: I tryed with this $("#ref01").contents().find("html").html().appendTo("#registration");

Comment: In inspector see this error : Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.webiste.co" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.website.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Answer (score 0):

In straight way you can not copy the content using contents() method of Jquery as it works only on same host.

You need to do something special to copy your iframe contents to div if that iframe is from different domain.

Refer to this post for the same issue. 
[Copy html content from iframe into div ( ajax )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113463/copy-html-content-from-iframe-into-div-ajax)